# Internationalizing my standalone application

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization, translation

I want my WinForms application to be available in three different languages, namely, Arabic, English, and French. The way I'm doing this for now is by using resource files (translation tables) and a recursive procedure that traverses the hierarchy of controls (root is the topmost Form) and assigns the translated version of each control's current `Text` to its `Text` property. The problem is that this does not work for menus (and other controls).

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. Please follow [Microsoft I18n Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688110). With Arabic you have more work to do (handle directionality correctly, using valid overloads for `MessageBox.Show()`, ensuring proper fonts, etc.) Take a look at [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/98358/2554) too.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to localise `System.Windows.Forms.Form` instances using the `Localizable` property. This then enables the `Language` property allowing you to change the locale as needed to make amendments to the form. These amendments are then stored in resource files suffixed with the locale (exactly the same as standard resource files). These then compile into satellite assemblies and the rest is handled by the CLR.

I have seen this used with mixed success - the VS designer has issues with Image Lists if I recall.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.100).aspx

There are advantages to rolling your own - however the UI is often *always* the main hindrance to this route.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should be using a different approach.

For each of your forms that you want to localize, go to the Form's properties and set its **Localizable** property to true.

Then from the **Language** droplist property, select a language that you want to support and enter the appropriate text.

Rinse and repeat for each language.

For the string table, you can add a new Resources.??.resx file for each language
(e.g. Resources.de.resx for German)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the language on the fly without restarting your application you need to use a function like this in association with what guys told you above.

```
//refresh all the controls e sub-controls of the form 
private void RefreshResources(Control ctrl, ComponentResourceManager res)
{
    ctrl.SuspendLayout();

    res.ApplyResources(ctrl, ctrl.Name, CurrentLocale);

    foreach (Control control in ctrl.Controls)

    RefreshResources(control, res); // recursion
    ctrl.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

If you want a more complete example check [my blog](http://codeuntil.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/localizable-forms-in-c-or-how-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Localizable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property of Winforms.

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43360/Globalization-Internationalization-I18N-and-Locali) has a nice walk through.

We broke up the resources in multiple resource files, some localized and some that were standard (non-display strings).  Then we used [Resourcemanager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to manage the strings.